# basel problem with an extra factor

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to solve an infinite series of the form:
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 2^{-n} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}$$

I know about the basel problem and its result:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$

And wolfram alpha actually tells me that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 2^{-n} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12} - \frac{\log^2(2)}{2}$$

But I can't find the steps to this solution, can someone give more details to the solution?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1207908, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2030643, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/466944 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D%20%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E2%202%5En%7D%24&p=1)